# Filtering by multiple attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, combo-box

I have a layer that contains multiple attributes in multiple fields that I would like to select between without needing to type out a query each time.

I am able to do this with extract by expression, but would like a way to make it more user friendly to switch between them on the fly, for example with cascading boxes or slicers. Is this possible?

Comment: If the expression is suitable for the filter option, duplicate your layer and filter each copy by a different expression (right-click a layer in the layer window to duplicate and/or filter it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Rule-based style, one for each 'slices'/expression.
You will then be able to choose in the layer panel what to see and what to hide.

In QGIS 3.4 you can configure your gradient style (choose attribute and Classify), then choose "category style", Qgis will create a rule for each value in your heat map.

Comment: Thanks, I have data values displayed as a heatmap with a gradient of colours, so I'm not sure that I can have both a gradient style and a category style?

Comment: in QGIS 3.4 you can configure your gradient style (choose attribute and Classify), then choose "category style", Qgis will create a rule for each value in your heat map.

Comment: Thank you Leo, this seems to be what I am after!